# In C# enter event triggered twice clicking on Combo box, but once when tabbing in

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, event-handling

I have a form that loads items into the Combobox dropdown when the user Enters the control. If you tab into the control, it works as expected. If you click on the control, the Enter event gets triggered twice.

Furthermore, the two triggers seem to run in parallel, not sequentially.

Any suggestions why this is? The net effect is I end up with double the items list.

This is the event handler:

```
private void cboTeam_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Current.matches.Count > 0)
    {
        cboTeam.Items.Clear();
        MatchRecord cm = Current.matches.FirstOrDefault(x => x.matchnumber == cboMatch.Text);
        if (cm != null)
        {
            string alliance = btnAlliance.Text.ToLower();
            string[] teams = (string[])cm.GetType().GetProperty(alliance).GetValue(cm, null);

            string[] teamnumbers = new string[3];

            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            {
                teamnumbers[x] = Current.teams.FirstOrDefault(tm => tm.key == teams[x]).number;
            }

            cboTeam.Items.AddRange(teamnumbers);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code from the form designer:

```
// cboTeam
// 
this.cboTeam.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
this.cboTeam.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
this.cboTeam.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.cboTeam.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(569, 31);
this.cboTeam.Name = "cboTeam";
this.cboTeam.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 28);
this.cboTeam.TabIndex = 5;
this.cboTeam.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cboTeam_TextChanged);
this.cboTeam.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.cboTeam_Enter);
```

Comment: I have an idea, but can you post the relevant code. It's hard to dissect without an example of your events and design.

Comment: @Tronald Sorry, I should have posted that to start with.

Comment: NP. Is this Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: It is a Windows Forms application.

Comment: Had a look and could not reproduce this issue. Are you sure you have not bound the handler twice? Can you run a find on the designer to see if the Enter event is bound more than once?